# How to make a PAM substack "requisite"?

Tags: scripting, pam

For the auth section of my PAM configuration, `login` and `mdm` etc. call `common-auth`.  I have `common-auth` calling the following as a substack (as `auth substack krb5ldap-cache-auth`):

```
auth optional pam_echo.so Trying UNIX
# Try UNIX, empty passwords OK
auth sufficient pam_unix.so nullok

auth optional pam_echo.so Checking UID
# If the uid < 500 and UNIX didn't work, then die.
auth requisite pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet_success

auth optional pam_echo.so Trying Kerberos
# Try Kerberos, using the same password
# If the password is correct (success), then skip next lines
# If the password is wrong (auth_err), then die
# If Kerberos can't connect (?), then ignore
auth [success=2 auth_err=die default=ignore] pam_krb5.so debug use_first_pass

# Try the cache, using the same password
# Last chance.
auth optional pam_echo.so Trying cache
auth [success=done default=die] pam_ccreds.so action=validate use_first_pass

# Kerberos validated our password.
auth optional pam_echo.so Kerberos validated
# Store the password hash.
auth optional pam_ccreds.so action=store use_first_pass
# See if we can mount user drives, since we have a Kerberos token.
auth optional pam_mount.so
auth optional pam_echo.so Done.
```

(Using `pam_echo.so` just for debugging.)

This seems to work fine for successful authentication. The substack mechanism is convenient, because I can use "sufficient" and "done" to terminate the substack without terminating the larger stack.

But for failing authentication, the larger stack continues (for example, `mdm` will uselessly call `pam_gnome_keyring.so`, `login` will uselessly call `pam_group.so`) when it ought to die.

Is there a way of calling a substack so that if the substack fails, the stack will die? I tried `auth requisite substack krb5ldap-cache-auth` but that's just bad PAM syntax.

Answer (score 2):

From the PAM administrator's guide:

> **`substack`**
>
> Include all lines of given type from the configuration file specified as an argument to this control. **This differs from `include` in that evaluation of the done and die actions in a substack does not cause skipping the rest of the complete module stack, but only of the substack.**

Reading your question, it seems to me like you are looking for `include` and not `substack`. Therefore you should probably replace...

```
auth substack krb5ldap-cache-auth
```

with...

```
auth include krb5ldap-cache-auth
```

On a Debian system however, you might have to use this instead:

```
@include krb5ldap-cache-auth
```

Also, on RedHat systems and derivatives, you might even have to use `pam_stack`, which is often considered to be deprecated (I believe due to issues in handling include recursions) :

```
auth requisite pam_stack.so service=krb5ldap-cache-auth
```

In these cases, if anything triggers a `done` or `die` action in `krb5ldap-cache-auth`, PAM will put an end to the **entire stack**, and not just the substack.

Comment: Where is that `@include` syntax documented??

Comment: @RobertSiemer This may help: http://www.rjsystems.nl/en/2100-pam-debian.php#incl